# XAMPP is not running in Window 8.1

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, windows-8.1

After upgrading Window 8 to 8.1 my XAMPP is not running. I can't access my phpmyadmin and getting `server not found` page.

My XAMMP Details:

> - Apache 2.2.11
> - MySQL 5.1.33 (Community Server)
> - PHP 5.2.9 + PEAR (Support for PHP 4 has been discontinued)
> - XAMPP Control Version 2.5 from www.nat32.com
> - phpMyAdmin 3.1.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you may have to put the port that it is running on. thats what i had to do, other than that does it give any errors when starting any of the services? 
also i found [this windows 8.1 compatibility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Name=XAMPP&vendor=Apache%20Friends&ModelOrVersion=1&Type=Software&tempOsid=Windows%208.1), and the majority of people have gotten it to work, so i dont think its an incompatibility problem.

Comment: Hi Michael I am still struggling to run XAMPP. I have reinstall but not working. Can you please help me.

Comment: whats not working? is there any errors when running or installing?

Answer (score 0):

Try change `www.localhost.com/phpmyadmin`  to

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

Comment: Hey Jason I tried but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Windows Defender not block applications needed to run XAMPP. On page [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) you can find "Attention..." about false-positives virus warnings. May be it solution. When I try to install XAMPP on Win8.1 x64 this displayed several messages about UAC disable, Antivirus etc.

Answer (score 0):

After Windows updating Apache and MySQL services are removed. So run xampp-control.exe as Administrator and add them (services) back. I had the same problem and this solved

Answer (score 0):

If you have SKYPE installed, either make sure you close SKYPE or disable "Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections" in SKYPE options.